# How to copy the subject of an email in a Subject of Mailto link?

Tags: outlook, hyperlink

I have icons in the signature of every email, which are used for feedback collection from customers. Every icon has a different hyperlink, generating a new email with a preset subject and body and sent to a mailbox. How can I take the subject of the original email and put it in the subject of the newly generated email?

Answer (score 0):

There is no trivial way. I suppose the `mailto://` protocol is used for generating a new email in the hyperlink. Outlook doesn't allow running JavaScript on the message bodies for security reasons.